Installing python packages without internet access: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
I have been trying to install python on a computer with no internet access. There are many threads here on how to do that. The basic process is
On the pc with internet, to freeze (pip freeze > requirements.txt), then download (pip download -r requirements.txt), transfer the downloaded packages to the pc without the internet, and then install (pip install --no-index --find-links <folder> -r requirements.txt
This did not work for me. I kept getting errors such as this one:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
The advice in various threads was to check the python version, the pip version, etc. I did all that, nothing worked. Using Python 3.11.5 on Windows 10/Windows 11.

Please answer in the answer box, not in comments. Comments are not searchable so if one searches she will not find your comment.

Also edit your question from installing python to installing python packages.

I was told I could reply to my own question but not include the answer inside the question, so here goes.
What worked for me was this:
Include --all in the freeze command.
pip freeze --all > requirements.txt; 

Include --no-build-isolation in the install command (possibly redundant, but it worked and I didn't want to change it) and use python -m pip install instead of pip install, because some of the packages seem to want to modify pip.
python -m pip install --no-index --no-build-isolation --find-links <folder with the downloaded packages> -r requirements.txt


Finally! The last thing to fix: proper code formatting; either triple backticks or 4-space indents.

@phd - thanks for taking the time to make all the corrections. Much appreciated.

Thank you for the work, now it's really good! Upvoted.
